# Ubuntu 13.04 wifi issues (realtek 8188ce)

Tags: wireless, ping

I have ping issues meaning that my ping is normal but I get lag spikes, ping reaching 500-600ms. I suspect there is something wrong with the drivers because on windows there is no problem. Also I have checked there are no interferences or anything else. Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance,
Marios

Answer (score 0):

After I installed good firmware From the DD-WRT wiki to drive the Broadcom chip in my Linksys wifi-router, I have had no more issues like the ones you speak of with my rtl8188 using the rtl8192ce driver. I first had to flash this, poor performing, [**E2500 Trailed Initial Flash Build**][1], before I could upgrade the firmware from the next link ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/others/eko/BrainSlayer-V24-preSP2/2012/06-08-12-r19342/broadcom_K26/dd-wrt.v24-19342_NEWD-2_K2.6_big-nv60k.bin. Like you, I've never had an issue using windows 7 on the same hardware. It turns out there's a bug with Broadcom chips using linux sometimes. Remember, there are at least two drivers from two separate cpu's involved in a wifi setup. I didn't even consider that until it was fixed. Good Luck bro!
-mchid

Comment: I am really grateful you took some time to answer, however I am new to the ubuntu scene so any tutorial on what to do with this file would be much appreciated. Thanks again for your effort :D

Comment: Using the DD-WRT made no difference for me on this card, but it did  fix the issues with my Intel wireless card.  This fixed me though: http://askubuntu.com/questions/352470/how-to-compile-realtek-8188ce-wireless-driver-on-ubuntu-13-04